# Defining a recursive product function

Tags: products

I have defined a non-commutative product:

```
ClearAll[M];
M[a___, b_ + c_, d___] := M[a, b, d] + M[a, c, d]; 
M[a___, 1, b___] := M[a, b]; 
M[a___, b_. c_, d___] := 
c M[a, b, d] /; FreeQ[c, R | t]; 
SetAttributes[M, Flat];
```

I would like to define an analogue of the usual `Product` function, in which I would input

```
NewProduct[Subscript[t, i], {i, 1, n}]
```

which outputs, for say `n = 3`,

```
M[Subscript[t, 1], Subscript[t, 2], Subscript[t, 3]]
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewProduct[x_, iter_] := M @@ Table[x, iter];
NewProduct[Subscript[t, i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

> M[Subscript[t, 1], Subscript[t, 2], Subscript[t, 3]]

Let `Table` handle the iteration and then replace the `List` it gives you with the head you want (in this case, `M`).

Note that this won't handle infinite iteration well. If you need that, you'll probably want to investigate the properties of your `M` function further to see if you can reduce it by hand or to already built-in functions.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method:

```
myProduct[expr_, {k_, kmin_: 1, kmax_}, times_: Times] := 
Array[Function[k, expr], kmax - kmin + 1, kmin, times]
```

Example:

```
myProduct[C[k], {k, 10}, Dot]
   C[1].C[2].C[3].C[4].C[5].C[6].C[7].C[8].C[9].C[10]
```

In your case, use your custom operation `M` as the third argument for `myProduct[]`.